# Mafia wars autoplayer shrinks Firefox

Tags: mafia-wars

How to solve this bug? As I play MW with autoplayer and I sent a gift to someone, my Firefox 3.6.12 starts to shrink gradually from right, so that I have to chose the tab while it is moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop every script from moving or resizing the browser by going to
  *File->Options->Content->Advanced (Next to "Enable Javascript")*
and unchecking "Move or resize existing windows", or similar, I'm using the latest beta, the feature has been around a long time but it might have been moved.